# MongoDB get previous one year record from today Including null dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

Unable to retrieve the list of previous one-year records from today Including null dates in node MongoDB from Contacts collection.

```
Sample Collection:
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5cb6a9ee8f145b97daf7181b"),
   "Name" : "David",
   "Age" : "25",
   "JoiningDate" : 2019-06-01T06:18:22.359+00:00
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5cb3a9ee8f1d1b75daf7181b"),
   "Name" : "Smith",
   "Age" : "28",
   "JoiningDate" : 2019-12-01T06:35:22.865+00:00
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5cb3r4ee8f1d1b75daf7181b"),
   "Name" : "Peter",
   "Age" : "23",
   "JoiningDate" : null
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4w7ee8f1d1b75daf7181b"),
   "Name" : "Maria",
   "Age" : "23"
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5cb9a9ee8f1d1b24daf7181b"),
   "Name" : "Alicia",
   "Age" : "24",
   "JoiningDate" : 2018-06-01T06:18:22.109+00:00
}
```

My Code is:

```
var collection = db.collection('Contacts');
var fromDate = new Date(Date.now() - 365*24*60*60 * 1000);
var data = collection.find({ $or: [{"JoiningDate":{$gt: fromDate}}, {"JoiningDate":{$eq: ''}} ]} );
```

What wrong I am doing, please correct me!

Comment: Update condition as ```db.getCollection('test').find({ $or: [{"JoiningDate":{$gt:fromDate}}, {"JoiningDate":{$eq: null}} ]})```

Answer (score 1):

As `undefined`,`null` and `someval` have different meanings, your query needs to cover all of these cases in order to retrieve all the data.

Use this query which utilises some basic boolean logic to achieve this:

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
    {
        $or: [
            {"JoiningDate": {$gt: fromDate}},
            {"JoiningDate": {$eq: null}},
            {"JoiningDate": {$exists: false}}
        ]
    })
```